# Wordpress, conditional arguments in wp_query, OR

Tags: wordpress, arguments, conditional-statements

Is this possible to add a condition OR to wp_query? Something like conditional arguments.
Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

Regular posts (post type 'post') in categories (by id): 10, 20, 30.
Post of other type (post type 'folio').

I'm trying to create a query (wp_query), which will display last 3 posts of type:

- 'post' from categories 10, 20, 30

OR

- 'folio'

So, if last three post by date are the posts of type 'folio', the 'category__in' will be skipped in the wp_query.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, It is not possible to make the conditions in the query itself, but of course it is possible to use conditionnal statements inside the loop. In other words, use a global query satisfiying all your needs, and then use `||` in the results to express your `OR`.